# ESonar server does not start up

Tags: sonarqube5.3

First time I am using SonarQube and after integration with  eclipse, I start the sonarserver but  I am getting the below error.

Error:

```
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | WrapperManager class initialized by thread: main  Using classloader:
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@70dea4e
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | Wrapper Manager: JVM #1
jvm 1    | Running a 64-bit JVM.
jvm 1    | Wrapper Manager: Registering shutdown hook
jvm 1    | Wrapper Manager: Using wrapper
jvm 1    | Load native library.  One or more attempts may fail if platform speci
fic libraries do not exist.
jvm 1    | Loading native library failed: wrapper-windows-x86-64.dll  Cause: jav
a.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no wrapper-windows-x86-64 in java.library.path
jvm 1    | Loaded native library: wrapper.dll
jvm 1    | Calling native initialization method.
jvm 1    | Initializing WrapperManager native library.
jvm 1    | Java Executable: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
jvm 1    | Windows version: 6.1.7601
jvm 1    | Java Version   : 1.8.0_60-b27 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
jvm 1    | Java VM Vendor : Oracle Corporation
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | Startup runner thread started.
jvm 1    | Control event monitor thread started.
jvm 1    | WrapperManager.start(org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp@3f99
bd52, args[]) called by thread: main
jvm 1    | Communications runner thread started.
jvm 1    | Open socket to wrapper...Wrapper-Connection
jvm 1    | Opened Socket from 31000 to 32001
jvm 1    | Send a packet KEY : 8vB3fcnsLty4gNaO
jvm 1    | handleSocket(Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=32001,localport=31000])
jvm 1    | Received a packet LOW_LOG_LEVEL : 1
jvm 1    | Wrapper Manager: LowLogLevel from Wrapper is 1
jvm 1    | Received a packet PING_TIMEOUT : 0
jvm 1    | PingTimeout from Wrapper is 0
jvm 1    | Received a packet PROPERTIES : (Property Values)
jvm 1    | Received a packet START : start
jvm 1    | calling WrapperListener.start()
jvm 1    | Waiting for WrapperListener.start runner thread to complete.
jvm 1    | WrapperListener.start runner thread started.
jvm 1    | WrapperSimpleApp: start(args) Will wait up to 2 seconds for the main
method to complete.
jvm 1    | WrapperSimpleApp: invoking main method
jvm 1    | 2016.03.02 11:06:16 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch pro
cess[search]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=tru
e -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:
+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingO
ccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\sri.laksh
mi.kovvuri\projectworkspace\SonarQube\sonarqube-5.3\temp -cp ./lib/common/*;./li
b/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer C:\Users\SRILAK~1.KOV\AppData\Local\Tem
p\sq-process1566850086740273426properties
jvm 1    | Send a packet START_PENDING : 5000
jvm 1    | Send a packet START_PENDING : 5000
jvm 1    | WrapperSimpleApp: start(args) end.  Main Completed=false, exitCode=nu
ll
jvm 1    | WrapperListener.start runner thread stopped.
jvm 1    | returned from WrapperListener.start()
jvm 1    | Send a packet STARTED :
jvm 1    | Startup runner thread stopped.
jvm 1    | Received a packet PING : ping
jvm 1    | Send a packet PING : ok
jvm 1    | Wrapper Manager: ShutdownHook started
jvm 1    | WrapperManager.stop(0) called by thread: Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook
jvm 1    | Send a packet STOP : 0
jvm 1    | Received a packet STOP :
jvm 1    | Thread, Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook, handling the shutdown process.
jvm 1    | calling listener.stop()
jvm 1    | WrapperSimpleApp: stop(0)
jvm 1    | returned from listener.stop() -> 0
jvm 1    | shutdownJVM(0) Thread:Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook
jvm 1    | Send a packet STOPPED : 0
jvm 1    | Closing socket.
jvm 1    | Wrapper Manager: ShutdownHook complete
jvm 1    | Server daemon shut down
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

**and in log file its coming the below error:**

```
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Using tick timer.
server listening on port 32001.
Launching a JVM...
command: "java" -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms3m -Xmx3m -Djava.library.path="./lib" -classpath "../../lib/jsw/wrapper-3.2.3.jar;../../lib/sonar-application-5.3.jar" -Dwrapper.key="n_2QZgO7FbHOC2G_" -Dwrapper.port=32001 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999 -Dwrapper.debug="TRUE" -Dwrapper.pid=4876 -Dwrapper.version="3.2.3" -Dwrapper.native_library="wrapper" -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout="10" -Dwrapper.jvmid=1 org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp org.sonar.application.App
JVM started (PID=7932)
WrapperManager class initialized by thread: main  Using classloader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@70dea4e
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

Wrapper Manager: JVM #1
Running a 64-bit JVM.
Wrapper Manager: Registering shutdown hook
Wrapper Manager: Using wrapper
Load native library.  One or more attempts may fail if platform specific libraries do not exist.
Loading native library failed: wrapper-windows-x86-64.dll  Cause: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no wrapper-windows-x86-64 in java.library.path
Loaded native library: wrapper.dll
Calling native initialization method.
Initializing WrapperManager native library.
Java Executable: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
Windows version: 6.1.7601
Java Version   : 1.8.0_60-b27 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
Java VM Vendor : Oracle Corporation

Startup runner thread started.
Control event monitor thread started.
WrapperManager.start(org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp@3f99bd52, args[]) called by thread: main
Communications runner thread started.
Open socket to wrapper...Wrapper-Connection
Opened Socket from 31000 to 32001
Send a packet KEY : n_2QZgO7FbHOC2G_
handleSocket(Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=32001,localport=31000])
accepted a socket from 127.0.0.1 on port 31000
read a packet KEY : n_2QZgO7FbHOC2G_
Got key from JVM: n_2QZgO7FbHOC2G_
send a packet LOW_LOG_LEVEL : 1
send a packet PING_TIMEOUT : 0
send a packet PROPERTIES : (Property Values)
Start Application.
send a packet START : start
Received a packet LOW_LOG_LEVEL : 1
Wrapper Manager: LowLogLevel from Wrapper is 1
Received a packet PING_TIMEOUT : 0
PingTimeout from Wrapper is 0
Received a packet PROPERTIES : (Property Values)
Received a packet START : start
calling WrapperListener.start()
Waiting for WrapperListener.start runner thread to complete.
WrapperListener.start runner thread started.
WrapperSimpleApp: start(args) Will wait up to 2 seconds for the main method to complete.
WrapperSimpleApp: invoking main method
2016.03.02 14:39:07 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[search]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\sri.lakshmi.kovvuri\projectworkspace\SonarQube\sonarqube-5.3\temp -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer C:\Users\SRILAK~1.KOV\AppData\Local\Temp\sq-process637648259402434916properties
Send a packet START_PENDING : 5000
read a packet START_PENDING : 5000
JVM signalled a start pending with waitHint of 5000 millis.
2016.03.02 14:39:07 INFO   es[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting search
2016.03.02 14:39:07 INFO   es[o.s.s.SearchSettings]  Elasticsearch listening on 127.0.0.1:9001
2016.03.02 14:39:08 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1456909746449] version[1.7.2], pid[6784], build[e43676b/2015-09-14T09:49:53Z]
2016.03.02 14:39:08 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1456909746449] initializing ...
2016.03.02 14:39:08 INFO   es[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1456909746449] loaded [], sites []
2016.03.02 14:39:08 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.env]  [sonar-1456909746449] using [1] data paths, mounts [[OSDisk (C:)]], net usable_space [32.7gb], net total_space [148.5gb], types [NTFS]
Send a packet START_PENDING : 5000
WrapperSimpleApp: start(args) end.  Main Completed=false, exitCode=null
WrapperListener.start runner thread stopped.
returned from WrapperListener.start()
Send a packet STARTED : 
Startup runner thread stopped.
read a packet START_PENDING : 5000
JVM signalled a start pending with waitHint of 5000 millis.
read a packet STARTED : 
JVM signalled that it was started.
send a packet PING : ping
Received a packet PING : ping
Send a packet PING : ok
read a packet PING : ok
Got ping response from JVM
2016.03.02 14:39:12 WARN   es[o.e.bootstrap]  JNA not found. native methods will be disabled.
2016.03.02 14:39:13 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1456909746449] initialized
2016.03.02 14:39:13 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1456909746449] starting ...
2016.03.02 14:39:14 WARN   es[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Fail to start search
org.elasticsearch.transport.BindTransportException: Failed to bind to [9001]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.bindServerBootstrap(NettyTransport.java:422) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.doStart(NettyTransport.java:283) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:85) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.doStart(TransportService.java:153) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:85) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode.start(InternalNode.java:257) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.search.SearchServer.start(SearchServer.java:45) [sonar-search-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:77) ~[sonar-process-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.search.SearchServer.main(SearchServer.java:79) [sonar-search-5.3.jar:na]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /127.0.0.1:9001
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:272) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport$1.onPortNumber(NettyTransport.java:413) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.transport.PortsRange.iterate(PortsRange.java:58) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.bindServerBootstrap(NettyTransport.java:409) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.2.jar:na]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss$RegisterTask.run(NioServerBoss.java:193) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.processTaskQueue(AbstractNioSelector.java:391) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:315) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss.run(NioServerBoss.java:42) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.2.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
2016.03.02 14:39:14 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1456909746449] stopping ...
2016.03.02 14:39:14 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1456909746449] stopped
2016.03.02 14:39:14 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1456909746449] closing ...
2016.03.02 14:39:14 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1456909746449] closed
send a packet PING : ping
Received a packet PING : ping
Send a packet PING : ok
read a packet PING : ok
Got ping response from JVM
Wrapper Manager: ShutdownHook started
WrapperManager.stop(0) called by thread: Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook
Send a packet STOP : 0
read a packet STOP : 0
JVM requested a shutdown. (0)
wrapperStopProcess(0) called.
Sending stop signal to JVM
send a packet STOP : NULL
Received a packet STOP : 
Thread, Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook, handling the shutdown process.
calling listener.stop()
WrapperSimpleApp: stop(0)
returned from listener.stop() -> 0
shutdownJVM(0) Thread:Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook
Send a packet STOPPED : 0
read a packet STOPPED : 0
```

JVM signalled that it was stopped.
    Closing socket. socket read no code (closed?).
    server listening on port 32002.
    Wrapper Manager: ShutdownHook complete
    Server daemon shut down
    JVM process exited with a code of 0, leaving the wrapper exit code set to 0.
    JVM exited normally.
    <-- Wrapper Stopped

Comment: Can you able to see the sonar console in chrome?

Comment: Yes  I am able to see the sonar console in chrome

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes SonarQube doesn't launch after several start/shutdown cycles and reports that couldn't make the "bind". For me, going to the "Task Manager" and close all the Java processes solves the problem.
It happens that somehow after closing the SonarQube console, something about that process is still running in the background and causes to block the ports to be used by SonarQube.

Answer (score 0):

First try to find out that specific port and stop it as it has not stopped gracefully.

```
netstat -a -o -n
taskkill /F /PID <port> #cmd command to stat and kill the process
```

If not sure then go to the

```
conf->server.propeties
```

and change the `sonar.search.port`